# Display an icon next to mouse cursor

Tags: windows, visual-c++

I am trying to display an icon next to the mouse cursor as long as my application is downloading a file. I am limited to visual c++. The changed cursor should be visible even outside my application.

Many applications like the Synaptics touchpad driver already does this. For instance, when you do pinch-to-zoom, a "move" icon is displayed next to the current cursor. 
http://blog.quppa.net/wp-content/uploads/cursor1.png

I checked `SetSystemCursor` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648395%28VS.85%29.aspx 
But this function can only change the entire cursor as a whole, and if the app crashes or terminates abnormally, the original cursor won't be restored.

Comment: Would drawing on the screen at the mouse's position with GDI work?

Comment: It only has to *look* like a mouse cursor, it doesn't have to *be* the real mouse cursor.  A full screen borderless transparent window is a classic trick.  A hook that traps WM_SETCURSOR would be another.